# Print ZZZ to AAA or ZZZ to 000 using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a series consisting of combinations of letters and numbers reversing through the alphabet and 9-0 like the following:

```
ZZZ
ZZY
ZZX
.
.
ZZ9
ZZ8
.
.
ZZ0
ZYZ
ZXZ
.
.
.
AAA
999
.
.
.
000
```

Comment: From ZZZ to ZYZ I had an idea what kind of series you might want, but then ZXZ does not match, nor do AAA+999. So what exactly do you want? And more important: what have you tried so far?

Comment: so are you using somekind of alphabet where it starts at 0..9 and continues to A..Z? [0,1,..,8,9,A,B,..,Y,Z]? If yes all you need are 3 nested loops and an array of chars

Answer (score 1):

Following code will print out the series from ZZZ to AAA:

```
var d1=91, d2=90, d3=90;
while(d1+d2+d3>195){
    if(d1>65) d1--;
    else if(d2>65){d2--;d1=90;}
    else{d3--;d2=d1=90;}
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(d3)+String.fromCharCode(d2)+String.fromCharCode(d1));
}
```

And you can add the following code after to print out the series from 999 to 000:

```
var d1=10, d2=9, d3=9;
while(d1+d2+d3>0){
    if(d1>0) d1--;
    else if(d2>0){d2--;d1=9;}
    else{d3--;d2=d1=9;}
    console.log(d3+''+d2+''+d1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, Base36 (you would need to 0..999 as an exception and add padding)

First 100:

```
var ZZZ = 46655;

for (var i = ZZZ; i > ZZZ - 100; i--)
    console.log(i.toString(36).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: I like your answer! Smart!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with simple nested loops like this:

```
var options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

for(var i=options.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    for(var j=options.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
        for(var k=options.length-1; k>=0; k--) {
            console.log(options[i] + options[j] + options[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfq1hzrt/).